# How to pass a dataframe read from excel to another variable in spark-scala?

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, spark-excel

I have a dataframe `var cache :DataFrame = _`. As an initial run i have given, `cache = existingDF`, the existingdf is read from an  excel using crealytics.spark.excel.
but in the subsequent run, the existingDF will get another updated excel file, it should be `cache = cache.union(existingDF)`
But I seem to get only  existingDF inside cache. In short whenever i call cache it seems to read the excel. How do i avoid this? This issue is not there while reading it as csv. (It was there when i used `.persist` on the csv read, but got fixed when i removed .persist
More Simply:

```
var a = _
while(true){
    val b = spark.read.format("com.crealytics.spark.excel")...
    if (Option(a).isEmpty){
      a = b
    }
    else if a!=b
      a = b.union(a)
}
```

The variable a is always getting updated along with b, so it never becomes different from b. How do I avoid this?

Comment: please post runnable code, as it stands now, the question is unclear (especially the title)

Comment: As @RaphaelRoth says, your question doesn't have enough information for us to help you.

Comment: Hope this edit helps

Comment: Are you iterating through a list of files? I'm still not clear what you are doing, if you clarify I'll post a functional answer (you almost certainly shouldn't be using a var or a while loop)